# getJSONP function to a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, jqlite

i have a getJSONP function that is being called from inside a prototype function. I am passing a JSON object to that function and changing values inside it, i want to be able to use the updated object after it's ready but i can't seem to return the object, only call a different function from the callback and use it there.

I thnink i understand the concept of promises but how can i change my function into a promise and use it when it is ready?

this is the getJSONP function:

```
function getJSONP(url, success) {
  var ud = '_' + +new Date,
    script = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;

  window[ud] = function(data) {
    head.removeChild(script);
    success && success(data);
  };

  url += '?callback=' + ud;
  script.src = url;
  head.appendChild(script);
};
```

And this is how i use it:

```
MyClass.prototype.mySpecialFunction = function(myObject) {
    getJSONP(myURL,function(data) {
      //doing alot of stuff
      ...
      //myObject.myArr = code the pushes a lot of stuff into an array
      workWithTheNewArray(myObject) // where i work with the full array
    });
});
```

please take into account that i am not using jQuery (because of performance and size), but i am using [jqlite](https://github.com/jstools/jqlite).

Comment: what promise you mean? [native Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or from some library?

Comment: @Grundy to tell you the truth i'm not sure... i think native would be the lightest option here(or am i wrong?) how well would it support IE9 ?

Comment: mdn say IE not supported Promise, even 11. i mean native promise. Also as i see jqlite - have no own promise?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use promises here? Is the callback not enough?

Comment: @Tomalak it's just that i need to return that object and use the new data i pushed in it's array and that ```return``` happens way before the data i need gets back

Comment: [You cannot return data from an asynchronous method.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) Again: Why not simply use the callback? There is no reason whatsoever to introduce another 3rd-party library dependency for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi , I went over that question as well as others, it just wasn't clear to me how to apply  it to my situation, i don't think it's a duplicate, just a more specific question, but maybe i'm wrong :)

Comment: @FireBrand: Yeah, but specific questions still can have generic duplicates :-) Also I didn't know whether you had seen it before, that's why I linked it (notice I didn't close - yet). It would've been helpful if you could have stated that you read it already, and tried something (but weren't sure?) and showed us the attempt. Or otherwise *please help us* improving the canonical reference by telling us what exactly has been left unclear there! Does it need better examples? A step-by-step howto?

Comment: @Bergi you're right, i should have mentioned what other questions i've investigated. a step-by-step howto would be great! I couldn't (and still can't) comment on the question for i haven't gained enough reputation yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using a [pormise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill), they claim it is lightweight and supports IE, then you can give the below code a try:

```
function getJSONP(url, success) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var ud = '_' + +new Date,
    script = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;

    window[ud] = function(data) {
      head.removeChild(script);
      resolve(data);
    };

    url += '?callback=' + ud;
    script.src = url;
    head.appendChild(script);
  });
};

MyClass.prototype.mySpecialFunction = function(myObject) {
    return getJSONP(myURL).then(function(data) {
      //doing alot of stuff
      ...
      //myObject.myArr = code the pushes a lot of stuff into an array
      workWithTheNewArray(myObject) // where i work with the full array
    });
});
```

Comment: And how would i work with things outside of  ```MyClass.prototype.mySpecialFunction``` that are waiting for it to finish? would a ```return``` inside the anonymous function work?

Comment: @FireBrand updated code, changed to `return getJSONP..`

Comment: Ok, so how should the call  to ```mySpecialFunction``` change from ```MyClass.mySpecialFunction(myObject)```?

Comment: Alright, i've played with this a little bit and changed to
 ```var prom = MyClass.mySpecialFunction(myObject)``` i managed to get it working, thanks!

Comment: Probably a better idea to use the core js polyfill, also there is no error handler here as Bergi mentioned. It's probably for the better to use `fetch` here and polyfill _that_ instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum do you or Bergi mind to elaborate? i would love to get more info and options

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine, and mido spent time writing it. Just because I have more experience doesn't make me more right. If I add an answer the only benefit it'll have is that it'll have my name on it and that's not really a benefit at all. All I suggested (which is comment worthy at best) is that browsers already contain a promisified API for requests called `fetch` and if you need to support older browsers you can just polyfill _that_. Regardless, you should not use JSONP anyway (use CORS  http://enable-cors.org/)

Comment: mido's answer works perfectly for me, just wanted to make sure i wasn't missing anything (like the ```error``` handler from Bergi's comment), thanks for all your help guys!